# Debugging [DebuggerHidden] method

Tags: debugging

My app uses DLL that calls another app with System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember.
I decompiled all modules and got source code with VS2022 so I can see the code of System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember, but it's marked as [DebuggerHidden] and I can't put a breakpoint in it. How can I debug this method?